# Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. OR statement

Tags: angular, jhipster

Being quite new to programming I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this.
`*ngIf="!report.approved` and `*jhiHasAnyAuthority="'ROLE_ADMIN'"` work separately so I'm guessing the OR statement is the problem. I've tried using a `<ng-container>` as suggested in some off the answers but I can't make it work. Is there any way to do something like this?

```
<button type="submit">View</button>
<div *ngIf="!report.approved" || *jhiHasAnyAuthority="'ROLE_ADMIN'">
  <button type="submit">Edit</button>
  <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</div>
```

Admins should always see the buttons and users should only see the buttons if the report is not approved.

Comment: Have you tried `*ngIf="!report.approved" || jhiHasAnyAuthority="'ROLE_ADMIN'"` ?

Comment: Yes. And it removes the buttons for every one

Answer (score 2):

A workaround would be to split the two directives in two different divs for the AND and duplicate the code if you want to achieve the OR, like this:

for **AND**

```
    <div *jhiHasAnyAuthority="'ROLE_ADMIN'">
        <div *ngIf="!report.approved" >
            //your html code here
        </div>
    </div>
```

for **OR**

```
   <div *jhiHasAnyAuthority="'ROLE_ADMIN'">
         //your html code here
   </div>
   <div *ngIf="!report.approved">
        //your html code here
   </div>
```

**still with this OR version you will get duplicated results if both conditions are met at the same time.**

Comment: Doesn't this change the outcome to an `AND` instead of an `OR`?

Comment: yes it does, I just updated the answer with the OR version. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Now it probably shows the html code twice (OR) when having both conditions evaluating to true.

Answer (score 1):

You may duplicate the code as below to get the desired effect.

```
<button type="submit">View</button>
<div *ngIf="!report.approved">
    <button type="submit">Edit</button>
    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</div>
<div *ngIf="report.approved">
    <div *jhiHasAnyAuthority="'ROLE_ADMIN'">
        <button type="submit">Edit</button>
        <button type="submit">Delete</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have some issues with the doublequotes and you need to add a `=` in the second statement. The part after `!report.approved` can't be reached because you are closing the `*ngIf` directive with the double quotes.

Can't check it right now but I guess this could work:

```
<div *ngIf="!report.approved || jhiHasAnyAuthority=='ROLE_ADMIN'">
```

Comment: Dosnt work. Both ngIf and jhiHasAnyAuthority are directives and far as i can tell they need the * to work